# sed: delete text between a string until first occurrence of another string

Tags: regex, sed

Imagine I have something like the following text:

**The quick brown fox jumps in 2012 and 2013**

And I would wish to delete the part from "fox" including the four numbers but only in the first occurrence so I end up with:

**The quick brown and 2013**

Something likes this...:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps in 2012 and 2013" \
   | sed  "s/fox.*\([0-9]\{4\}\)//g"
```

...brings me:

```
The quick brown
```

So it removed everything including the last occurrence of the four numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: The standart quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning they match as much as they can.

Answer (score 6):

POSIX regular expressions used by `sed` (both the "basic" and "extended" versions) do not support non-greedy matches. (Although there are some workarounds, such as using `[^0-9]*` in place of `.*`, they become unreliable if the inputs vary a lot.)

What you need can be achieved in Perl by using the `?` non-greedy quantifier:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps in 2012 and 2013" \
   | perl -pe 's/fox.*?([0-9]{4})//g'
```

You might wish to remove an extra space as well.

Comment: Damn it, outninja'd. What is that about the extra space, though? (+1)

Comment: @grawity: Try adding a space after the right parenthesis.

Comment: Are the parentheses useful?

Comment: @Scott: Not really in this case :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use *only* sed and you want the end of the match to be the first group of digits, without caring what the word is after the digits, this works:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps in 2012 and 2013" \
   | sed "s/fox[^0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][0-9]* //"
```

The pattern works by matching `fox`, followed by one or more non-digits `[^0-9][^0-9]*`, followed by 1 or more digits `[0-9][0-9]*`. This pattern will work with an arbitrary number of digits, not just 4. If you want to match exactly 4 digits, change it to:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps in 2012 and 2013" \
   | sed "s/fox[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\) //"
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify *exactly* what your requirements are.  You may want a multi-step process.  Pick a string that you know will not occur in your input (e.g., `####`):

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps over 42 lazy dogs in 2012 and 2013." \
  | sed \
        -e "s/[0-9]\{4\}/&####/" \
        -e "s/fox.*####//" \
        -e "s/####//"
```

(Command excessively folded for readability.)  The `-e "s/[0-9]\{4\}/&####/"` injects `####` after *the first* four-digit number.  (Warning: this will change `65536` to `6553####6`.)
`-e "s/fox.*####//"` affects lines that contain `fox` and `####` -- i.e., lines which contain at least one four-digit number -- and then deletes from `fox` through *the first* four-digit number.
`-e "s/####//"`, of course, cleans out any `####` strings that are left over from lines that contain a four-digit number but not `fox`.

To also remove one space after the number if there is one,

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumps over 42 lazy dogs in 2012 and 2013." \
  | sed \
        -e "s/[0-9]\{4\}/&####/" \
        -e "s/fox.*#### //" \
        -e "s/fox.*####//" \
        -e "s/####//"
```

Warning: You can add `g` to all the `s` commands, but, since this still uses `.*`, which is the root of your problem, it will still not handle

```
One fox jumps in 2012 and 2013, another fox will jump in 2014 and 2015.
```

the way you probably want.  And, of course, you ***don't*** want to add `g` to `"s/[0-9]\{4\}/&####/"` because then it will inject `####` after *every* four-digit number, defeating the whole point.  Then the `"s/fox.*####//"` will end up acting just like `"s/fox.*[0-9]\{4\}//"` (your original command with the non-contributing characters removed); i.e., it will change

**The quick brown fox jumps in 2012 and 2013.**

to

**The quick brown fox jumps in 2012#### and 2013####.**

and then to

**The quick brown .**